# GA4 - View & Share Custom Reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I know this should be an easy one but I can't figure this out.

I've created a custom report (User traffic with some different cards) in GA4.  I can see the report by clicking on Reports tab / Library and its shown in the Reports list.

If I click on the report, I can edit it and customize the Report Data, Summary Cards, Charts, etc...

But where do I simply "View" the report?  I want to view the report, change the date filter, and possibly share the report like all the pre-built Reports (eg. User acquisition, Traffic acquisition, etc...)

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the new report you will need to add it to an existing or new collection. Collections are the groupings you see in the left column under reports. The simplist way to do this is to go to Reports and then select the Library. At the top of the Library page you will see a list of existing collections. Click on the "Edit collection" link on one of the existing collections where you think your report should reside. You will see a page with two columns, the collection and its topics in the left and  a list of reports, including your custom report on the right. Drag your custom report from the right column and drop it under one of the topics in the left column. Click on the Save button and then go "Back". You will now find your report ready to use under the collection and topic you added it to.